# Log Excel triggered events

Tags: vba, excel, events, logging

I'm looking for a way to log all the triggered events of an Excel file.

The file I want to use it for is large (around 160 sheets) and has multiple event procedure on Workbook and on the different Worksheets. 
**Adding some code in each Event sub is thus not an option due to the amount of subs**.

Does anyone know of a tool or a VBA trick to be able to log those?
Logging all procedure calls would also be an option.

Comment: Use a `WithEvents` workbook variable to which you assign that workbook. You can then monitor all its events without disturbing existing code.

Comment: I managed to do so for Workbook events, any ideas on how to do so for Worksheet events?

Comment: There are workbook level equivalents for all the sheet events, so you can trap them with the same variable.

Comment: Worksheet events like `worksheet_change()` or events that are triggered by buttons etc *on the sheets*?

Comment: You're the man! It works, thank you!
@Raystafarian, if i can the buttons that great too. Any idea?

Comment: `worksheet_selectionchange()` *should* capture them, but it would run pretty much constantly, so you'd need to qualify it